# How to get lines of code searched by a scm account in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have got two tasks, first is to find the lines of code from the projects in the Sonarqube server. That can be simply done by   `api/measures/component` including the ncloc. The second task is to get the lines of codes of specific developer(author/scm account). Ive searched the API, read articles about this, i cannot find a way to do this. I would like to a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API call in Sonarqube for the current version 7.5 . However if you have connected SonarQube through Jenkins, or if the project is updated in Git, you can find the lines of code of a user